# Can we dynamically create links with React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Imagine I wanted to create a web application with React like Instagram where users can add pictures. Every picture added is then associated to a single URL, like this one :

https://www.instagram.com/p/BTg4ZopggE9

How can we do that?

I know there is this module 'react-router' but as far as I know, it works only with a predefined set of routes that the programmer has hard-coded (The URLs can't be created dynamically).

Comment: You can pass params to routes, like `/p/:image_id` where image_id is a variable

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params is the *second* link in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is true that the routes in react-router are pre defined, the params can be dynamic. For instance, you can have a route like `/images/:imageId`, ImageId would be nothing more that a variable name to hold the image id. Now when a user would navigate there they would see the url like so, `/images/12ert56` or something like that. Then the component to which they were routed to will read the image id out of the param by calling `this.props.params.imageId` and then the component will show them the corresponding image.